# how to Show BEFORE TEXT before in wordpress get_comment_meta

Tags: php, comment-meta

I am using a piece of code to show the city output. It is working fine. The code is given here:

```
$city = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'city', true );
```

I want to show Re: text before the output of above code.

Comment: If you just want to add a string it would be `$city = "Re: " . get_etcetera.`. Else I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Great that helped. I've included it as an answer. Pleas accept it, so this question does not pop up later as "unsolved":

Comment: @cjbj this will in all probability be closed, need one close vote to close this as off topic as it is generic PHP. Also note, a question is considered answered when it has an upvoted answer. It is always much better to have an accepted answer, but a question do not need an accepted answer to be considered answered by the system

Comment: @PieterGoosen I know. But I also know we have a large close-vote-backlog, so I follow both paths.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add a string it would be:

```
$city = "Re: " . get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'city', true );
```